# What's with the new Community Evaluation review process?

Tags: discussion, site-health

Seems like StackExchange rolled out a new reviewing process - the [Community Evaluation review queue](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/community-eval) today.

While it is a good idea to review those answers to determine the quality of them, there is a varying degree on how we deem an answer to be Excellent, Satisfactory or Needs Improvement.

So the question is: Do we have any basic standards that the various quality answers have? It seems like someone can mark an answer as Excellent and another person may mark it as Satisfactory, and what difference does it make to the reader?

Comment: it's not exactly new - the last one was in November/December. It comes up periodically.

Comment: Oh, I am still quite new to Web Apps in such areas, but let's just start defining the standards now

Comment: Here's some more details on the evals [Which questions need Community Evaluaton?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161039) and background [Strategies for handling beta community quality evaluations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115988)

Comment: Seems like it is a gauge on whether the site needs help in the quality of the answers. It appears every 90 days for us.

Comment: Heh. [I asked about it, too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165994/community-evaluation-on-established-sites).

Comment: Just adding that the event is already over a few days back

Answer (score 3):

[According to Adam Lear ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166036/21960)

> This is new. Now that we no longer have to run site evaluations manually ourselves, we figured  we would expand them to graduated sites.
>
> Tim Stone hit the nail on the head in [his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165994/community-evaluation-on-established-sites#comment485273_165994):
>
> > Maintaining quality over time is just as important as starting off on the right foot.
>
> Now, this *is* somewhat experimental. If these evaluations prove too distracting or not particularly helpful on graduated sites, we'll turn them off. In the meantime, the queue should pop up for a week every 90 days.

Comment: This does answer the original question, though I have shifted my focus to having a discussion on what our standards are so as a facilitate future reviews. Thanks for this answer though, I have already read about it in the links provided in the comments.